# after updating dynamic gridview in asp.net it is showing multiple values in each row why

Tags: c#, asp.net

here i am going to update multiple values at a time by using single button click

On clicking update button for gridview it is showing multiples values for each and every column

After refreshing the page it is showing normal  data

For example if i am inserting 1 in 1st column, 2 in 2nd column after updating gridview it is showing 1,1  2,2 like that

Comment: Can you place your code ?

Comment: I developed my code using 3 tier architecture

Comment: Add a code bit , which you have tried/...

Answer (score 0):

Because your gridview has autogeneratecolumn = true. change to false.

Or if you want custom header name do this steps:
in gridview property (Design part) click `edit columns -> your boundfield -> under its property`, you can see the "DataField", set your field name of your database. You can see now the data of your records from your database. also you can set header name.

Comment: in my program autogeneratecolumn = false even it is like that only

Comment: in gridview i kept single button with the help of single button i am trying to update multiple rows              here rows are updating but showing previous value also